# Scaling Images in HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a number of objects that represent an image that I want to draw onto a canvas. Each object has a X, Y, Scale property as well as a render method that gets passed a canvas object. then the canvas tag is passed to each object's render method and they all need to render themselves to the canvas.

The problem I have is that scaling is being done from the origin of the canvas and not the origin of the image. To fix this I've tried the following:

```
canvas.translate(-this.X, -this.Y);
canvas.scale(this.Scale, this.Scale);
canvas.translate(this.X, this.Y);
```

The problem with the above code is that it looks like you can only have 1 translation and the 3rd line which is supposed to move the object back to its original position becomes the translation when calling drawImage. If I remove the 3rd line I get the correct scaling origin but the image is moved to 0,0 and not rendered in the correct location.

What is the proper way to do this type of scaling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
canvas.translate(this.X, this.Y);
canvas.scale(this.Scale, this.Scale);
canvas.translate(-this.X, -this.Y);
```

But keep in mind, doing this you will need to do alot of `ctxt.save();`s and `ctxt.restore();`s if you got the width and height of the imagens you could simple do `ctxt.drawImage(this.image, this.X, this.Y, this.Width*this.Scale, this.Height*this.Scale);` since you don't need to mess with the context state stack it may be faster.

Edit:

The transformations don't affect the origin. What happen is that they must be applied in [reverse order](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#transformations). Remember this methods are just shortcuts for stacking matrices in the transformation stack.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding how translate is working, wouldn't line 1 translate all points +this.X, +this.Y away from there original position?

Comment: Ahhh looks like translate actually moves the origin. Life makes sense now. Thanks!